# Does free() set errno?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management

If `buf` is a `malloc()` allocated char buffer, does `free(buf)` set/reset `errno`?

Let's say I want to write the buffer to a file, and then free it, as I don't need it any more.

Let's say the error policy for the code is to return -1 on an error.

Is this a proper way to write out the buffer and error check without leaking memory?

```
fputs(buf, somefile);
free(buf);
if (errno) return -1;
```

Or do I need to consider free possibly setting errno, as in...

```
fputs(buf, somefile);
if (errno){ 
    free(buf);
    return -1;
}
free(buf);
```

or, horror of horrors,

```
do { 
  fputs(buf, somefile);
  int save_errno = errno;
  free(buf);
  errno = save_errno;
  if (errno) return -1;
} while(0);
```

where the use of a block allows for a local save_errno to exist in various places should this need to be reused.

All of this would seem to depend on whether free() sets errno.

The [linux man page for free()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) is also the man page for `malloc()`, etc.  It mentions `malloc()` setting errno, but not `free()`.

The [GNU C Library manual page for freeing dynamic memory](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Freeing-after-Malloc.html#Freeing-after-Malloc) does not mention whether free() sets errno.

So I wrote a short program to force a write error so I could see if free() reset errno, and it does not.  I'm wondering if I should rely upon this result and the fact that free() is so essential that "of course it doesn't set errno."

```
# See if free() resets errno on a bad write
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char * buf = malloc(256);
  snprintf(buf,256,"%s\n", "Hello, World!");

  FILE *badfile;

  badfile = fopen("/dev/null","r");

  fputs(buf, badfile);
  free(buf);
  printf("%d\n", errno);
  printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

Comment: A [good reference should help](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/free.html).

Comment: Also, the value of `errno` is undefined after calling functions which doesn't explicitly set it, and that includes function calls which doesn't fail. In other words, don't check `errno` unless the *previous* call explicitly failed.

Comment: @Joachim My C is a bit rusty, but I do seem to recall that misuse of free simply crashes.

Comment: "Misuse" of `free`, like attempting to free the same pointer twice, doesn't *have* to crash, it's simply *undefined*. Though undefined behavior in many cases leads to crashes.

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/errno.html#tag_16_110

Comment: You don't need to resort to a `do {...} while(0);` construct, you can also create blocks with simple braces `{...}`.

Comment: Before `fputs` do clear `errno` otherwise you might get false positives. Also saving `errno` is a good idea as is volatile: `printf(3)` calls `write(2)`which might change `errno`.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

POSIX doesn't define [`free`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/free.html) to set `errno` (although POSIX doesn't currently forbid it, so an implementation might do so - refer to [@ArjunShankar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30571921/822669) for more details). But that's not really relevant to your concern.

The way you're checking for errors is incorrect. You should check the return value of `fputs`, and check if it's smaller than `0`. If it is, then you can check `errno` to find out what caused the failure, but that's optional (and should be done before calling any further functions).

So, something like this should do the trick :

```
int result = fputs(buf, somefile);
/* optionally read errno here if result < 0 (before the free call) */
free(buf);
return (result < 0) ? -1 : 0;
```

Comment: Relevant quote from the `errno` man page: `Its  value  is  significant  only when the return value of the call indicated an error (i.e., -1 from most system calls; -1 or NULL from most library functions); a  function that succeeds is allowed to change errno.`

Comment: @Mark: Fun fact: I managed to observe that `execvp()` changes `errno` on success.

Answer (score 40):

A POSIX compliant `free` might set `errno` *today* but this is going to change for the better in the future. Details:

1. The [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) definition of [`errno`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/errno.html) states the following:

> No function in this volume of POSIX.1-2008 shall set errno to 0. The setting of errno after a successful call to a function is unspecified unless the description of that function specifies that errno shall not be modified.

2. The definition of [`free`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/free.html) itself does not specify what `free` does with `errno`.

What this means is that a compliant `free` implementation will never reset `errno` to 0. But it may or may not set it to a non-zero value.

*However, Issue 8 (a work in progress) of the specification will [require `free` to specifically guarantee that it will not set `errno`](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=385) when passed a valid input.*

[glibc](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17924) is already gearing up to adhere to this new requirement.

Comment: Under what circumstances might free set errno when passed a valid input?

Comment: @Random832 That would depend on the implementation. Maybe some don't touch `errno`. Look at the glibc bug report (but to be clear this isn't a bug yet, since POSIX hasn't been revised yet) I linked to on the last line of my answer, for details on how it can happen in glibc's implementation of `free`.

Comment: @Random832 Imagine a malloc/free implementation that tried to shrink the heap when possible, using system calls approriate to the underlying OS, e.g. mmap(), sbrk(), etc.  If these system calls fail, errno would be set.

Comment: @Random832, it's perfectly valid for a function to unconditionally set `errno` to the most common error and then use the return value to indicate whether that error actually occurred.

Answer (score 17):

There is nothing said about `errno` in the description of `free` in the C Standard. So you may not rely on this feature.

According to the C Standard (7.5 Errors `<errno.h>`)

> 3...The value of errno may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an error, provided the use of errno is
>   not documented in the description of the function in this
>   International Standard.

And the use of `errno` is not documented in the description of `free` in the C Standard as I have already said above.

Answer (score 13):

If the reference doesn't say that a function returns an error code in `errno` on failure, it won't.

Functions that set `errno` to an error code (almost) always signal in another way that `errno` contains the current error code - the memory allocation functions return `NULL`, many other functions return zero or a negative number, and so on.
Such functions are not required to modify `errno` in any way if they succeed, and usually don't.

You usually can't inspect `errno` to determine whether something went wrong; it is only meant for retrieving more information once you know that there has been an error.

One exception to the final rule is the `strto{l, d, ul}` family, but the first paragraph is true for those as well.
And they also don't necessarily set `errno` except when they fail, so you need to clear it first or it may contain a stale error code.

Comment: That's not true. A well-known exception is `strtol`: you're required to clear errno beforehand and check it upon receiving a valid value (LONG_MIN or LONG_MAX) if you want to detect certain error conditions.

Comment: @Random832 Interesting. I added a bit about the `strto*`s.

Answer (score 0):

Yes free() may clobber errno on various systems. gnulib avoids this issue by replacing free() on such platforms, which it documents currently as:
"glibc 2.32, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD 4.4, Minix, AIX, HP-UX, IRIX, Cygwin, mingw, MSVC"

Answer (score -3):

you can use RAII to free malloced memory, and check the return value of fputs. That will be grace code.

```
//if malloc successfully
AutoFree af(buf);
if (fputs(buf, somefile)) {
LOG("something err:%s", strerror(errno));
}
return 0;
```